# Codeigniter Flash data Message in Modal window :Edited

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

I have a View page **company_view** which displays all the information of a college,  has its own controller **company.php** to fetch results from the DB via the model.

Added a Modal Form to this page where the user inputs his details and it sends that data to the DB. 
In other words a Custom registration form.

http://startcodeigniter.blogspot.in/2015/12/create-simple-contact-form-in.html

But the above form is inside a modal.

The Insertion Process succeeds but I want the Success message to be displayed in the modal itself, it redirects into another page => (the new controller page **contactform/index** ) after submitting the form.
Went through a few solutions to fix it , but nothing seemed to work out.

Is there any AJAX way to submit the data to the controller which prevents it from redirecting?
Been scouring for similar AJAX example, still no luck.

What i was looking for is when the user submits the data, the modal displays that the data is submitted without the redirection.

Any help / Lead would help me a great deal!

**Updated View - company_view.php**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#enquire">Enquire</button>


    <div class="modal fade" id="enquire">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Apply for "<?php echo $row_company->company_name;?> "</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <?php $attributes=a rray( "name"=> "contactform"); echo form_open("contactform/index", $attributes);?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('name'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email ID</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email-ID" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('subject'); ?>" />
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('subject'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message">
                    <?php echo set_value( 'message'); ?>
                </textarea>
                <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('message'); ?></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
            </div>
            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
            <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller for form - contactform.php**

```
<?php
class Contactform extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation'));
        $this->load->database();
    }

    function index()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_alpha_space_only');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Emaid ID', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'trim|required|xss_clean');

        //run validation on post data
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {   //validation fails
            $this->load->view('company_view',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the contact form data into database
            $data = array(
                'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
                'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'subject' => $this->input->post('subject'),
                'message' => $this->input->post('message')
            );

            if ($this->db->insert('contacts', $data))
            {
                // success
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">We received your message! Will get back to you shortly!!!</div>');
                redirect('contactform/index');
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Some Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('contactform/index');
            }
        }
    }

    //custom callback to accept only alphabets and space input
    function alpha_space_only($str)
    {
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$str))
        {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('alpha_space_only', 'The %s field must contain only alphabets and space');
            return FALSE;
        }
        else
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you want to display flash message inside the model or just want to open a model when the flash message came??

Comment: Either of the two would do, But preferably 2nd one , Just to show the data is sent . The post is Edited completely, Might get a better picture now.

Comment: ok, i will answer it shortly but please keep this simple thing in mind that Here at SO you can get a perfect suggestions or answer of your problem but for that you need to ask properly and to the point directly. Here you have just posted all of your code(i think) which is not recommended you should put that code which you think might be not working or you don't get what to do after that. I am suggesting because a good question always get the solution on SO.

Comment: @ankitsuthar, You're right. I edited the question and made it even more complicated, Will revise and put up a less complicated one.

Answer (score 0):

There is a unorthodox method I have used.

Put your modal in your html page with your flashdata like.

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="messageModal" role="dialog">
 <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('msg'); ?> 
</div>
```

then in your script tag load that modal if flashdata is set

```
<?php if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('msg')) { ?>
 <script>
    $(window).on('load',function(){
       $('#messageModal').modal('show');
    });
 </script>
 <?php } ?>
```

This might not be the best answer.But definitely a way to do this.
All suggestions or improvements are welcome/welcomed

Comment: Whenever i try submitting the form in the modal, it redirects it to the new controller even when the new controllers view is commented out

Comment: its obvious a form will direct you to the action page.
So whats the problem? You manage your data in controller and finally doing all stuff pass a flashdata that it you need. And i have given you the process example above.

Comment: I want the form not to redirect after submission , is there any way to achieve that ?
instead it should show another modal or a dialog which says data successfully submitted. Tried doing what you told, after i entered both the codes, The view wasn't loading, Blank page. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please ask your question properly .As it will help others as well.
For your case you need to submit form using ajax as it won't close your modal and on success or failure of ajax call change text of your modal window(pop up html).

Comment: I'll rectify the question and make it less confusing, My bad. and yes like you said, I guess Ajax is the way to go. Can you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

@Zeehan Akhtar Mohammed here the answere. When user enters the details in form and clicks on submit the data is inserted to database and `$this->session->set_flashdata()` success message is shown in modal..As you said

view/college_view.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">Contact Form</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <?php 
                    $attributes = array(
                        "method"=>"post",
                        "id"=>"contactform"
                    );
                    echo form_open('Contactform/get_data',$attributes);?>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" type="text" value="" required/>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email ID</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email-ID" type="text" value=""  required/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="subject" placeholder="Subject" type="text" value=""  required />
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="4" placeholder="Message"required></textarea>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" class="btn btn-success">
                </div>
                <?php echo form_close();?>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
            <?php
                if($this->session->flashdata('report') !=   ''){
                ?>

                    <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#myModal").modal();
                    });
                    </script>
                    
                <?php
                }
            ?>
    </div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1 class="text-center"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('report')?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller/Contactform.php

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Contactform extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('html');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        //LOAD SESSION LIBRARY HERE 
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
    
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('college_view');
    }
    
    public function get_data(){
        $submitbtn=$this->input->post('submit_button');
        if($submitbtn == true){
            
            $arr = array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'subject'=>$this->input->post('subject'),
                'message'=>$this->input->post('message'),
            );
            
            //NOW INSERT THE DATA TO DATABASE   
            $this->db->insert('CI_input',$arr);
            
            if($this->db->insert_id() == true){         
                $this->session->set_flashdata('report','Data successfully inserted');
                redirect('Contactform/index');
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Error";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

### NOTE YOU CAN ADD HELPERS AND LIBRARIES IN AUTOLOAD.PHP PAGE IN CONFIG FOLDER BUT TO SHOW I ADDED IN `__construct` method##

### Feel Free to ask

Comment: Not getting any errors, Just that i want the flash data to be shown in the modal itself or as a dialog.

Comment: @ZeehanAkhtarMohammed even in my code the flash data is shown in itself.